# How to fix the UnknownHostException in java

Tags: java, rest, hp-alm

I am trying to access the HP ALM rest api to get the login authentication tokens using java but the rest api throws UnknownHostException.

```
private static final String almURL = "https://myalmUrl.com/qcbin";
private static final String isAuthenticatedPath = "authentication-point/authenticate";
public static String strUserName = "username";
public static String strPassword = "password";

    private static String getEncodedAuthString() {
            String auth = strUserName + ":" + strPassword;
            byte[] encodedAuth = Base64.getEncoder().encode(auth.getBytes());
            String authHeader = "Basic " + new String(encodedAuth);
            return authHeader;
        }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
            client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().build();
            target = client.target(almURL).path(isAuthenticatedPath);
            invocationBuilder = target.request(new String[] { "application/xml" });
            invocationBuilder.header("Authorization", getEncodedAuthString());
            res = invocationBuilder.get(); // error occured
    }
```

**error :**  `Exception in thread "main" javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.net.UnknownHostException: myalmUrl.com`

What is the problem in this code? how can i fix it?

Comment: Enter a valid URL…

Comment: You could meet the host?

Comment: Make sure the connectivity is proper and the URL is valid

Comment: I suspect you are copying code from a tutorial, and that tutorial intended the reader to replace “myalmUrl.com” with the name of their actual HP ALM host, instead of typing `myalmUrl.com` literally in the code.

Comment: i am using my working alm url  i just replaced with `myalmUrl.com`  for posting in stackoverflow

Comment: i am using alm 14 is login authentication url correct? or any changes needed `https://myalmUrl.com/qcbin/authentication-point/authenticate`

Answer (score -1):

Reason: Usually the UnknownHostException fires when you cannot resolve the DNS record of the URL you've provided. There's a reasonable timeout for that operation, but if you have a weak Wi-Fi connection or you don't have enough signal on your device, the communication can be interrupted in the middle between sending a request and receiving a response, so your device doesn't receive a response, thus it thinks it's a DNS timeout.

Long story short, there are two main reasons for an exception:

1. If your Wi-Fi signals are weak.
2. If your device connected to the Wi-Fi but no internet is not
   available.

Solution: Before request check availability of the internet using `HttpURLConnection` class.